# Jquery dynamic element behavior issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

> Please be aware that this is not a duplicate off :
>   [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements/34937304#34937304][1])

Not long ago I was struggling with Jquery dynamic event binding but finally got it to work. The syntax I was using was :

```
$(document.body).on("change", "#registerF > input,  #registerF > select", function () });
```

`#registerF =` Id of the form.

`input, select` = The elements.

And everything was working fine until believe it or not, i decided to change all my links in my site with a variable for better portability.

**Was:**

```
http://example.com/path/to/file.php
```

**Became :**

```
var host = "http://example.com";
host + '/path/to/file.php';
```

All the sudden my jquery dynamic element triggering went off so I looked at it.

I have changed it for :

```
 $(document.body).on("change", "#registerF * ", function () {});
```

And it is working but in a weird way.

The event get triggered  and this is where it gets weird:

```
 $(document.body).on("change", "#registerF * ", function () {
  var field_id = ($(this).attr("id"));  <--- is defined
  alert(field_id);  <-------------------- display the id
  var container = ['#' + field_id + "_ck", '#' + field_id + '_err'];
  var data_type = ($(this).attr("data-type")); 
  var value = document.getElementById(field_id).value; <--- ERROR point here
  alert(value) <----- display the good value as being defined
```

The script is working. the values are interpreted as they should yet I get this error in the console

---

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

(anonymous function) @ Script.js:254

m.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4670

r.handle @ jquery.js:4338

---

My Jquery version is from :
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

have changed it to 1.12 and still the same.

So I'm totally blown here. How van the value get sent if its undefined!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a lot of extra work to get the id, pass it to another dom search to look for the element again, and then get value after that search when `this` is already available in the event handler and is the element

Can simplify this down to

```
$(document.body).on("change", "#registerF :input ", function () {
   alert(this.value);    
});
```

I have no idea what you are trying to do creating the array `container`

Comment: They are the element that receive the answer. will try with this.value

Comment: Thank you sir!  What is the diffrence between the :  and > ?
Like #id : element and #id  > element

Comment: `>` denotes child only...not all descendants. `:input` is a pseudo selector for form controls  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/